# Bounds on multiplicities in tensor products of irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

**Question about representations of finite groups**

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $V_{\lambda}$ and $V_{\mu}$ be irreducible representations of $G$. Then their tensor product decomposes into irreducibles
$$ V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{\mu} = \sum_{\nu} m_{\nu} V_{\nu} $$
with multiplicities $m_{\nu}$.

I am looking for upper bounds on the multiplicities $m_{\nu}$. In particular, I'm wondering if it is always true that
$$ m_{\nu} \leq \mathrm{dim}(V_{\nu}). $$

**Generalisation to representations of finite dimensional Hopf algebras**

Same question, but now for representations of general Hopf algebras.

**Attempts so far**

I've checked the claim $m_{\nu} \leq \mathrm{dim}(V_{\nu})$ in quite a few cases using the formula
$$ m_{\nu} = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}  \chi_{\lambda}(g) \chi_{\mu}(g) \chi_{\nu}(g)^* $$
where $\chi_{\nu}$ is the character of $V_{\nu}$ etc., and using character tables from [this page](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/characters.html).

I have spent some time scouring the literature for a result, but found nothing so far.

Comment: Not sure about the claim, but it immediately implies that the multiplicity is in fact bounded by the smallest of the dimensions, since you can move tensor products to the other side in the inner product by taking a dual (which has the same dimension).

Comment: When $V_\lambda$ and $V_\mu$ are dual, this follows from the standard embedding $V_\lambda\otimes V_\lambda^*\hookrightarrow\mathbb C[G]$ of $G$-representations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following short proof, answering the question about representations of finite groups in the affirmative, is due to Gian Michele Graf.

We assume without loss of generality that we are dealing with unitary representations.

For any $f_1, f_1 : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ we write
$$ \langle f_1, f_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{| G |} \sum_{g \in G} \overline{f_1(g)} f_2(g). $$

As in the question, we denote by $\chi_{\lambda}$ the character of the irreducible representation $V_{\lambda}$.

Note that
$$ | \chi_{\lambda}(g) | \leq | \chi_{\lambda}(e) | = \dim V_{\lambda} $$
for all $g \in G$ and all irreps $V_{\lambda}$. Indeed, $\chi_{\lambda}(g)$ is the sum of the $\mathrm{dim} V_{\lambda}$ eigenvalues of $V_{\lambda}(g)$, each of which has modulus one, because we deal with unitary representations.

Now, if
$$ V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{\mu} = \sum_{\nu} m_{\nu} V_{\nu},$$
then
$$ m_{\nu} = \langle \chi_{\nu}, \chi_{\lambda} \chi_{\mu} \rangle = \langle \chi_{\nu}^{1/2} \overline{\chi}_{\lambda}, \overline{\chi}_{\nu}^{1/2} \chi_{\mu} \rangle. $$
By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$ m_{\nu}^2 \leq \langle \chi_{\nu}^{1/2} \overline{\chi}_{\lambda}, \chi_{\nu}^{1/2} \overline{\chi}_{\lambda} \rangle \cdot \langle \overline{\chi}_{\nu}^{1/2} \chi_{\mu}, \overline{\chi}_{\nu}^{1/2} \chi_{\mu} \rangle. $$
We can bound the first factor as
$$ | \langle \chi_{\nu}^{1/2} \overline{\chi}_{\lambda}, \chi_{\nu}^{1/2} \overline{\chi}_{\lambda} \rangle | \leq \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi}_{\nu}(g)^{1/2} \chi_{\lambda}(g) \chi_{\nu}(g)^{1/2} \overline{\chi}_{\lambda}(g) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} | \chi_{\nu}(g)| \overline{\chi}_{\lambda}(g) \chi_{\lambda}(g) \leq \mathrm{dim} V_{\nu} \langle \chi_{\lambda}, \chi_{\lambda} \rangle = \mathrm{dim} \, V_{\nu}$$
where we used $| \chi_{\nu}(g) | \leq \mathrm{dim} V_{\nu}$ for all $g \in G$ and $\langle \chi_{\lambda}, \chi_{\lambda} \rangle = 1$ because $V_{\lambda}$ is irreducible.

The second factor is bounded by $\mathrm{dim} V_{\nu}$ in the same way. We conclude that
$$ m_{\nu} \leq \mathrm{dim} V_{\nu}$$
as required.